# While(1) works first four times that function is called, then becomes infinite. (C)

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, infinite

I have a tic tac toe board that I'm working on for fun and I've come across a problem. Basically I generate the two x,y coordinates randomly and then run them through a while loop. If the coordinate position hasn't been marked, then it marks the spot. Else it'll continue running and generate a new pair of coordinates. This seems to work for the first four times that the function is called, but then any subsequent uses of the function cause it to spiral out of control. Hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction as well as tell me if logic is incorrect somewhere. Constructive criticism is great.

Thanks in advance and here's the code for the X's move function (the O has almost the same code):

```
void Xmove(struct config *cp) {
    int ran1, ran2;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    ran1 = rand() % 3;
    ran2 = rand() % 3;

    if(cp->grid[1][1] == ' ') {
        cp->grid[1][1] = 'X';
        printGrid(cp);
        return;
    }

    while(ran1 == 1 && ran2 == 1) {
        ran1 = (rand() % 3);
        ran2 = (rand() % 3);
    }

    int looper = 1;

    while (looper) {
        if(cp->grid[ran1][ran2] != 'O' && cp->grid[ran1][ran2] != 'X') {
            cp->grid[ran1][ran2] = 'X';
            printGrid(cp);
            looper = 0;
        }

        ran1 = (rand() % 3);
        ran2 = (rand() % 3);
    }

}
```

Comment: @djechlin If I've made an easy mistake, then please explain and I'd really appreciate it rather than pretty much typing an irrelevant comment. Thanks.

Comment: You are randomly selecting a position and then stopping the loop by setting looper to 0. While 0 isn't going to execute, so the loop would stop.

Comment: If the board is full, i.e. every element of grid has an 'O' or 'X', the loop will run forever.

Comment: @ProgrammingThomas right because the function is run for each turn of the game. It doesn't compute everything at once. So my idea was for it to run through the grid and check the position and like I said, if it's not taken already then mark it and set looper to 0 so that the otherwise infinite loop will stop.

Comment: @Eric That's taken care of with a different function. Right now I'm just individually calling my Xmove or Omove functions a certain number of times in my main function for testing.

Comment: `srand((unsigned) time(NULL));` <- call `srand` only once per process (or possibly thread). Don't call it every time you enter the function. Unless your tictactoe thing is unusually slow, you will get the same coordinates every time for a while.

Comment: The hitting around looking for empty slots is a bit awkward. If you just had a list of empty slots and randomly selected/removed one of those you would solve the infinite loop problem - because there would be no loop. Also, you would not waste time retesting slots that are not open.

Comment: "(the O has almost the same code)": Interesting. It should be *identical* code, and in fact, only should be only one *function* with the move-char being passed as a parameter, `void Move(struct config* cp, char who)` where `who` is either `'X'` or `'O'` makes me wonder whether you're intentionally tilting one side to win.

Comment: @WhozCraig well I'm using an example and the way the source's tester works is that it requires a separate function for each type of move. Obviously it's better programming practice to do as you said. Thanks for questioning it though.

Comment: @MarkStevens What do you mean by "a list of slots"? Originally I thought I would have an array with all 9 possible positions and then just mark them as I went through. However that still requires a loop, so I'm not sure whether or not that's what you mean. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Josh The 3x3 grid is intuitive of course for Tic-Tac-Toe, but a separate, linked-list maybe, that initially contains all 9 entries would be handy too. Then you could just have a MarkSquare('X' or 'O') function that both updates the grid and removes the corresponding entry from the list at the same time. Of course, the 3x3 grid is so small, you could just generate a list of open slots right when you need it - you wouldn't avoid the loop, but the loop would be finite (always 9 iterations). Then instead of 'looking around', you'd just generate a rand# between 0-list.size()-1, and pick that spot.

Comment: I don't know that for such a small grid there would be a significant advantage in keeping it as a list. Converting his "random, potentially infinite loop" to a finite one (9 iterations) will make a huge difference in getting this program to work predictable and be understandable.

Comment: @MarkStevens as Nik said, it would probably be overly-complex and messy to implement a linked-list in this situation since it's such a small grid. Unless it would make the situation that much more efficient of course. Just an FYI but this is C, not Java ;)

Comment: @NikBougalis readability is a plus here so I'm open to whichever way works most cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

Back to the the original question about your infinite loop and your code, You cannot make the loop break solely on the assumption of finding an empty slot and filling it. You should not be even *entering* the loop if there are no slots left available. In fact, you should not even call either Move() function at all if there are no open tiles to fill, and honestly that should be maintained as a decrement-counter of the config struct.

But that aside, detection of open-tiles-remaining could be done a number of ways. One is presented below that requires no other modifications to the config table, etc. This you can *easily* do by building a list of viable tiles, and choosing a *single* random entry from that. The following replaces *everything* past your initial check for the center slot being open.

```
// build a table of open tiles
int ar[9] = {0};
int n=0,i=0,j=0;
for (i=0;i<3;++i)
  for (j=0;j<3;++j)
    if (cp->grid[i][j] != 'O' && cp->grid[i][j] != 'X')
      ar[n++] = i*3+j;

// now you have the list of available tiles 
//  in `ar[0..n-1]`. choose ONE via `rand()`
if (n > 0)
{
    n = ar[rand()%n];
    cp->grid[n/3][n%3] = 'X'; // or 'O'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd eliminate the random looping altogether, instead every time I needed to make a move I would generate a random permutation of the digits 0-9 inclusive, and use that to walk the board, looking for where to put an X or an O as needed. Something like this:

```
    int randperm[9], i = 0;     

    /* fill the array randperm with the numbers 0 through 8 in 
     * order
     */
    for(i = 0; i != 9; i++)
        randperm[i] = i;

    /* Now mix the numbers up, so that the array ends up in
     * some "random" order: that is, generate a permutation
     * of the digits 0-8.
     */
    for(i = 8; i > 0; i--) 
    {
        int j = rand() % (i+1);
        int temp = randperm[j];
        randperm[j] = randperm[i];
        randperm[i] = temp;
    }

    /* Now try to find a spot. We will use our randperm array to
     * determine which cell to look at. Remember that the array
     * contains the numbers 0-8 in some random order.
     */
    for(i = 0; i != 9; i++)
    {       
        /* We split a number from 0-8 into two numbers (x and y), 
         * each from 0 to 2:
         *
         * 0 -> 0 0, 1 -> 1 0, 2 -> 2 0,
         * 3 -> 0 1, 4 -> 1 1, 5 -> 2 1,
         * 6 -> 0 2, 7 -> 1 2, 8 -> 2 2
         *
         * notice that (y * 3) + x = randperm[i]
         */
        int x = randperm[i] % 3;
        int y = randperm[i] / 3;


        /* check if the spot at grid[x][y] is available, if it is
         * take it and return. 
         */
    }

    /* If we get here there's no spot to put an X or an O... board is full */
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, but could you explain what you mean by making a list of random permutations?

Comment: The first loop fills randperm[] with the numbers 0-9 in order. The second loop 'mixes' the array up, so that the numbers are all mixed up. One time you may get 7, 3, 9, 0, 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, 4 and another you may get 1, 9, 5, 3, 2, 7, 6, 0, 4, 8. In the third loop you use that "random order" to step through the entire grid. Try running this code and printing out randperm after the second loop, and looking at how x and y are generated.

Comment: I added some more comments in the code. They should help you see what is happening and how the code works. I hope this helps.